# Is there a way to tell if I've successfully joined a squad?

Tags: guild-wars-2

On the wiki page for [Squad](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Squad), it says:

> Squads are limited to 30 players.

In the past, when I've right-clicked on a commander's icon and selected "Join Squad", I didn't receive any visual feedback that I had joined. I now suspect that it's because it was full. **Is there a way to tell whether you are in a commander's squad after trying to join?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just click on the little right-arrow on the top left, i.e. at the top of your party info. There, you'll see options to invite players to your party etc. as well as whose squad you have joined. For instance, see the wiki's entry on [Party](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Party) and look at the top right image (it would show your squad commander instead of "Not in a squad" if you'd joined one).

However, being in a squad in no way forces you to "stick with your commander" or obey their commands, etc. (Please see Gwen's comment below.)

Comment: You don't have to be in a squad for the commander to see your supply- you just have to be within range of the /supplyinfo the commander uses. /squadjoin is very much not a tool for the commanders but for the followers, because it hides all other commanders on the map (making it easier to follow the commander you picked).

Comment: Ah, that explains a few things for me - thanks @Gwen :-)